# Dynamic Twitter card images

Tags: ajax, twitter

I'm creating some images from WP posts using HTML5 Canvas and saving them to my uploads folder. I'm then sharing them to Facebook, which works fine, but to share to Twitter I need to update the Twitter Meta tags with the image URL's. I'm aware I can't do this with JS and need to do it server side, but I can't work out how to to this...

I'm using the following function in functions,php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_canvasUpload', 'canvasUpload');
add_action('wp_ajax_canvasUpload', 'canvasUpload');

function canvasUpload(){
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$img = $_POST['uploadImage'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);


global $file;
$uploads = wp_upload_dir(); 
$file = $uploads['path'].'/'. uniqid() . '.png';
echo $file;

return 
$r = file_put_contents($file, $data);
echo $r ? $file : 'Error saving file';
}




function add_twitter_cards() {
    if(is_single()) {
    $tc_url    = get_permalink();
    $tc_title  = get_the_title();
    //$tc_description   = get_the_excerpt();

    global $post;
    global $file;

    $tc_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );
    $tc_image_thumb  = $tc_image[0];
    $tc_author   = str_replace('@', '', get_the_author_meta('twitter'));
?>
    <meta name="twitter:card" value="summary" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" value="@elegantthemes" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" value="<?php echo $tc_title; ?>" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" value="" />
    <meta name="twitter:url" value="<?php echo $tc_url; ?>" />
<?php global $file; ?>
      <meta name="twitter:image" value="<?php echo $file; ?>" /> 
        <?php if($tc_author) { ?>
        <meta name="twitter:creator" value="@<?php echo $tc_author; ?>" /> 
        <?php

    }
    }
}
```

add_action('wp_head', 'add_twitter_cards');

and an AJAX call which currently shares the images to Facebook:

```
    $(document).on('click','.twitter',function(e){

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
    action: 'canvasUpload',
    uploadImage: data
    }
    }).done(function(o) {
      var url = o.split('uploads');
      var fileURL =  $("#fileURL").html(url[1]);
      var imgURL = $('#imgURL').html();
      var finalURL = imgURL + $("#fileURL").html().replace("png0", "png");;
      
 window.open(
          'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+ finalURL +'',
          "popupFacebook",
          "width=650, height=270, resizable=0, toolbar=0, menubar=0, status=0, location=0, scrollbars=0"
        );
       });
    
        return false;
    });
    });
```

Any help much appreciated,

Comment: WP does not have twitter opengraph tags, those come from 3rd party plugins, you would need to ask their support or check their docs for how they store that data

Comment: Thanks! I'm adding the Twitter meta tags with the add_twitter_cards function which I've added to my code above. I basically just need to be able to find the URL of the file that's just been added to the uploads folder and add it into the Twitter image meta tag. I'm still not quite sure how to do this though...

Comment: I'd suggest you 1) change your upload script to include the page URL; 2) get your AJAX handler to parse the page URL into a post ID, and then store the uploaded image URL in a post meta value against the post; 3) look up that meta value from your add_twitter_cards to find the image. (I don't know how to do all of that off the top of my head to write an answer.)

Comment: brilliant, thanks! That makes a lot of sense. I'll give it a go but if anyone else has any code examples that would be gr8 as my PHP is not so hot !